# Do While Loop not skipping the file it is supposed to

Tags: vba, loops, excel, do-while

I am building a macro to open every file in a folder, check if it is shared, unshare it if it is, save it, and close it. It is embedded in a file within that folder `LockFolder.xlsm`, so I need it to skip the file it is in, or else it will shut itself down midway through the loop.

There was originally an `If Filename <> 'Lockfolder.xlsm' Then` which worked fine, but I had trouble with nesting the If statement `If Activeworkbook.MultiUserEditing` in there, so I thought it might be easier to just put the former in the "Do While" section of the code.

It isn't working. The code still opens the file I want it to skip then closes it, aborting the whole thing only a few files into the loop.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Unshare()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim cPwd As String

    FileName = Dir(CurDir() & "\" & "*.xls")
    Do While FileName <> "LockFolder.xlsm" Or FileName <> ""
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbooks.Open (CurDir & "\" & FileName)
        If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
            ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not skipping your special file is because you've used `or` in the `do while`.

*Any* string will either be not a or not b since it cannot be both a and b at the same time:

```
FileName            <>"LockFolder.xlsm" (a)   <>"" (b)   a or b
-----------------   -----------------------   --------   ------
"LockFolder.xlsm"   false                     true       true
""                  true                      false      true
<all others>        true                      true       true
```

Note that I haven't included a line in the above for the `false/false` case, since I had a *very* hard time finding test data that would generate it :-)

You also will have the problem that your loop will terminate when it finds your special file, possibly skipping some it shouldn't.

You need your `do while` to simply check the termination value `""` and use an `if` within that to skip:

```
Do While FileName <> ""
    If FileName <> "LockFolder.xlsm" Then
        :
```

Comment: In this case, using the filename to terminate the loop was part of the problem, not so much the logical operators in the condition.

Comment: Jimmy, the use of `or` is specifically what caused the non-skipping, early termination is an _extra_ problem caused by the combining (even if you used `and`).

Comment: I tried it with "And" first, I should have specified. The same thing happened in either case.

Answer (score 4):

your problem is that your while loop exits as soon as it finds the file called `"LockFolder.xlsm"`.

you need to not make your while loop exit condition dependent on this file and instead just skip this one file in the loop

this line:

```
Do While FileName <> "LockFolder.xlsm" Or FileName <> ""
```

is the problem. you don't really want to stop looping if you find this `"LockFolder.xlsm"` file, only if the FileName is empty. so change it to this:

```
Do While FileName <> ""
```

and then just check for the file name you want top skip *inside* the loop, and just skip that one file

```
Do While FileName <> ""
    If FileName <> "LockFolder.xlsm" Then
        ...
    End If
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileName = Dir(CurDir() & "\" & "*.xls")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While FileName <> ""
  If FileName <> "LockFolder.xlsm" Then
      With Workbooks.Open(CurDir & "\" & FileName)
        If .MultiUserEditing Then
          .ExclusiveAccess
          .Save
        End If

        .Close
      End With
  End If

  FileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```